# Finding a general form of the density function when we have a four dimentional random variable.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability, statistical-inference

Consider a subject having time of the specific event $T_i$, which is a single sample from a
distribution $F_i$ with density $f_i$ and support
$[t_{\min},t_{\max}]$, for $i= 1,\ldots,n$. Let these subjects be
interviewed at times $S_1,\ldots,S_n \in [t_{\min},t_{\max}]$,
respectively. Let $\varepsilon_i$ be the indicator of recalling the age at that event and $\delta_i=I_{(T_i\leqslant S_i)}$.
Let $ V_i=(S_i-T_i)\varepsilon_i\delta_i, $ and $ Y_i=(S_i,V_i,\delta_i)$. Its clear that $Y_i$ is non negative random variable which had density with respect to proper measure. Let $t_1<\ldots<t_{j}<\ldots<t_{n_2}$ are observed points of random variable $T_i$ $(n_2<n)$ and
\begin{equation}
\bar{F}_i(t)=[\bar{F}(t)]^{\exp(\beta^TZ_i)},  
\end{equation}
where $\bar F=1-F$.

The joint density of $X_i=(Y_i,Z_i)$ is 
$$  p_{\beta,F}(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n_2} \alpha_{ij}\big[\bar F(t_{j})^{e^{z_i\beta}}-\bar F(t_{j+1})^{e^{z_i\beta}}\big]g(z_i)$$
where $g$ is the density of $Z$ and 
\begin{equation}
 \alpha_{ij} = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 I\big(t_j\in (s_i,t_{max}]) & \mbox{if}~~ \delta_i=0,\\
 \mbox{Constant}.I\big(t_j\in [T_i,T_i]) & \mbox{if}~~ \delta_i=1,\ (s_i-T_i)>0,\\
 \mbox{Constant} .I\big(t_j\in ((s_i-x_l,s_i-x_{(l-1)}]) & \mbox{if}~~\delta_i=1,\ (s_i-T_i)=0.\\
\end{array} \right.  
\end{equation}
if $x_{l-1}< x_l,\ l=1,2,...,7$ are fixed ordered points.

The question is what is the general form of the density of $X$? In other word what is $p_{\beta,F}(y,z)$?

I tried to write the probability in the following form 
\begin{equation}
 p_{\beta,F}(x)=\int \alpha(y,t')d\left(1-\bar F(t')^{\exp(\beta^Tz)}\right)\times g(z). 
 \end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \alpha(y,t') = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 I\big(t'\in (s,t_{max}]) & \mbox{if}~~ \delta=0,\\
 \mbox{Constant}.I\big(t'=s+u) & \mbox{if}~~ \delta=1,\ v>0,\\
 \mbox{Constant} .I\big(t'\in ((s-x_l,s-x_{(l-1)}]) & \mbox{if}~~\delta=1,\ v=0.\\
\end{array} \right.  
\end{equation}
if $x_{l-1}< x_l,\ l=1,2,...,7$ are fixed ordered points. But the problem is if the distribution of $T$ is continuous by the second form of $ \alpha(y,t')$, we will have $p_{\beta,F}(x)=0.$

I will appreciate your effort and answers.